# how to simplify these steps for a php array diff with 3 sql queries

Tags: php, sql, array-difference

How to simplify these steps? The php/sql code aims at deleting party_id's from one table that are not present in another table:

```
// party_id from one table
$array1 = array();
$db->setQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(record) FROM table1");
$contents = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach( $contents As $content ){
    $row = $content->record;
    $array1[] = $row;
}

// get party_id from different table
$array2 = array();
$db->setQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(party_id) FROM table2 WHERE user_id = '$id'");
$contents = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ( $contents As $content ) {
    $row = $content->party_id;
    $array2[] = $row;
}

// Compare, then delete records existing in array2, but not in array1
$result = array_diff($array2, $array1);
foreach ( $result As $rslt ) {
    $db->setQuery("DELETE FROM table2 WHERE party_id = '$rslt' AND user_id = '$id'");
    $db->query();
}
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM table2 WHERE party_id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT(record FROM table1)) AND user_id=$id`

Comment: DELETE FROM table2 WHERE party_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(record) FROM table1) AND user_id = '$id'; worked for me and is the simplest code on this page for the purpose given.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using a sub query to delete these records? You could use the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause to delete non-duplicate rows

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table2 
WHERE party_id in (SELECT DISTINCT(party_id) FROM table2 WHERE user_id = '$id')
and party_id not in (SELECT DISTINCT(record) FROM table1)
AND user_id = '$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using not exists:

```
DELETE 
FROM 
  table2 AS t2 
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.party_id = t2.record)
AND
  t2.user_id = '$user_id';
```